# Drools on Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, drools

I am starting a project where we have a lot of business rules. I have strongly been considering using the JBoss rules engine, Drools.

My project uses Scala and uses the Spark engine. I am wondering if anyone has experience, or advice, using Drools with Spark/Scala.

If you looked into Drools and decided against it, I would like to know that too.

I have read several blogs on how people integrate Drools with Spark, or Drools with Scala, but I didn't find any good examples explaining Drools on Spark with Scala. I have seen this with a mixture of Scala and Java, but never pure Scala. I am not sure if this is possible.

**Update: Clarifying Question**

1. Would you recommend Drools?
2. How about with Spark/Scala?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Hi finally what have you decided? With drools or with out drools?

Comment: I landed up going with Drools. It has been working out really well so far. The most difficult part is how the rules are authored. I have thousands of rules which makes it difficult to maintain in the DRL files and decision tables. The drools workbench also is not ideal for my situation. I will land up designing an in-house authoring tool.

Answer (score 1):

> If you looked into Drools and decided against it, I would like to know
>   that too.

I would not advise that. We are forced to use drools in one of our components and all developers in a team find this solution full of cons:

1. **Java 8 support**: scala is moving towards java 8 (see [this](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1#required-java-version) and
   [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0) regarding runtime). Drools started to support java 8 only
   in 2 years after its release.
2. **IDE support**: eclipse only. We were not able to get it done in
   Intellij idea.
3. **General purpose**: we did come up with the idea, that whatever you
   write using drools rules engine could be written in java/scala
   easily. You would say that business logic can get too technical?
   Possibly, but you would not have to learn some kind of scripting language
   to create business rules.

Comment: Number 3 is highly debatable. Once you've tried to go beyond the "Cheese" examples of the Drools manual you'll find that solving the many-many matching problem is, in general, more easily done with a rule based engine. Nested loops of a depth of three or more with possibly complex logic at each level to filter the desired components *can* be written but will usually turn out to be a nightmare for maintenance. - Note that there are decisioning systems with less overhead than Drools, but this does not mean your #3 is a universal truth.

Comment: 1. Could you explain more on what you mean about Java 8?
2. I would use the KIE workbench. Have you been using this?

Comment: I don't think 1. and 2. are really valid points against Drools. 3. really depends on the complexity of your rules, as they could be much easier to maintain as DRLs compared to the corresponding Java / Scala code.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, I would recommend Drools. I have no experience with other rule engines, but the projects I have developed using Drools have worked perfectly so far. Truth be told, I have only used the basic functionality of Drools (never used salience explicitly, Agendas, etc). However, the functionality I have used has solved my requirements perfectly.

2) I have used Drools with both Java 7 and Scala 2.11. I haven't found any particular thing I was able to do with Java but not in Scala. My latest project is using Apache Spark with Scala and Drools, and everything fits together nicely.

If you are going to use Scala, then your facts (the objects that model your domain; aka the 'bean') should have public access modifiers on the val or var you are going to access within the rules. If you need static methods or attributes, then use Objects and import them in the rule file.

Hope this helps